# Pell type equation: $x^2-py^2=a$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p=4k+1$ be a prime number such that $p=a^2+b^2$, where $a$ is an odd integer.Prove that the equation $$x^2-py^2=a$$ has at least a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A standard way to find $a,b$ begins by expanding $\sqrt p$ in a continued fraction; if you stop halfway through the period of the continued fraction, somehow you get $a$ and $b$. I bet solving $x^2-py^2=a$ is related to this. Sorry I can't be more precise.

Comment: $p=13$, $a=3$, $x=4$, $y=1$.

Comment: @Sil, I think the idea was to prove that for *every* such $p$ there's at least one solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Ah, in my defence, that wasn't made very clear.

Answer (score 4):

See e.g. Gary Walsh, [On a question of Kaplansky"](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/AlbanianJ.pdf).

Comment: The Albanian Journal of Mathematics!

Comment: Thank you, Franz. I remember Kap corresponding with Mollin about a bunch of conjectures, Mollin sent a short pdf with a proof of one of them, I had not realized Mollin published them(2001). Campus has C.R...Canada in bound volumes, but no scan and post service in this case, I will need to go borrow the actual volume and do my own copying.

Comment: Abstract here: http://mr.math.ca/Vol_23/No_2.html